# Pandas. Groupby. Cut. IntervalIndex. Generated in a dataframe and applyed to another

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, intervals

I'm trying to generate intervalIndex based on a dataframe (df_one), and then add a column in **another** dataframe (df_two) clasifying its values using that Intervals. The difficulty is that I'm using groupby.

I have this, for only one dataframe

```
df_one['bins'] = df_one.groupby(category)[value].transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins = breaks_maker(x),precision=2).astype(str))
```

What I would like to do is to save the intervals generated in the code above to pass them to another "bins" pd.cut applyed to another dataframe, also **by groups**.

dataframe one would be like:

[image]

Desired ouput **(i put "etc" instead the intervals, because i haven't generated them from df_one, but the output should be like/similar to row one)**:

[image]

Any help would be great!

If it is needed, "breaks_maker" is the function to generate intervals:

```
def breaks_maker(x):
 iq = (x.quantile(.75) - x.quantile(.25)) * 1.5
 limites = np.array([min(- 999999999, (x.quantile(.25) - iq)),
               x.quantile(.25) - iq,
               x.quantile(.25),
               x.quantile(.75),
               x.quantile(.75) + iq,
               max(9999999999, (x.quantile(.75) + iq))
               ])
 if x.drop_duplicates().shape[0] < 5:
    return(5)
 else:
    return(pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(limites))
```

Comment: Can you convert dataframe to text format for possible processing? Also `Desired ouput` is second DataFrame? Or no second DataFrame in question?

Comment: Yes, desire output is df_two. No, i think you cant convert to text format because you cant create intervals from text.